# Debugging a SQL command in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server, debugging

So below I have a piece of code that I have been working on:

```
SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection("Server=OMADB01;Database=PATRICK_DEV;Trusted_Connection=True;");
connect.Open();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("UPDATE FILE_DATE_PROCESSED SET FILE_DATE_PROCESSED = DATE_ENTERED, DATE_ENTERED = GETDATE() SELECT top 1 FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, DATE_ENTERED FROM FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, ORDER BY DATE_ENTERED DESC ", connect);
SqlDataReader reader = null;
reader = command.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    Console.WriteLine(reader["FILE_DATE_PROCESSED"].ToString());
    Console.WriteLine(reader["DATE_ENTERED"].ToString());
}

connect.Close();
```

This code is supposed to write out the contents of the datatable I have in SQL, however I keep getting an error message that ORDER is incorrect syntax, however that is false because when I take that statement and put it in my query in SQL, it works. I am new to using SQL in c# so I am not quite sure how to debug with SQL statements, so if someone could please help me figure this out I would very much appreciate it!

Comment: Well, ORDER is in incorrect syntax alright, there's a comma in "FILE_DATE_PROCESSED, ORDER BY "

Comment: You should try your sql statement in sql managment studio before adding it to the C# app to eliminate most common problems.

Comment: I would prefer to see your code not so tightly coupled with the data. Changing this to use a stored procedure and moving your data to the procedure would be a good start in making your application have layers. It is hard to figure out what you are trying to do here because you are going to update all rows in your FILE_DATE_PROCESSED table to the same value.

Comment: I'd say go the stored procedure route too - it means you don't need to redploy an app if you need to change the implementation. Also it looks like you are trying to run an `update` which depends on the value of a `select` from the same table (and depends on `getdate()`) - in which case you shouldn't need the select at all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot have two calls, update and select without having `;` in between.

Comment: The Order By is on the Select statement.  He is mixing two calls.  Update then Select.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing two statements.  "Select" and "UPdate".

First try putting a ";" between the two statements.

Second:
Try running Only the Select portion.